# Use a textarea for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-admin

I have a custom plugin, using a custom post type for data entry capabilities in the admin section.  I would like to use a textarea form, along with the checkboxes, select and text input fields I am presently using.  However when I update the bost, my call back receives all the other input fields, not not the textarea field.

The code is rather large, covering lots of different input types, this is a refinement of that draw and save call:

```
function  CustomInput()
{
add_meta_box( 'List_Group1',
           __( 'Lists - Card Records : Manual Input', 'myplugin_textdomain'  ),
              'DrawCallBack',
              'customlist',
               'normal',
               'high',
               $args
               );           
 }
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'CustomInput' );
 add_action( 'save_post', 'SaveFields');


function DrawCallBack($post)
{
$Record = GetDBRecord();
echo '<textarea id="bizdesc" rows="2" cols="50">';
echo $Record['BizDescp'];
echo  '</textarea>';

echo '<input type=text id="YourName" name="YourName"  value="' .$Record['Name'] .'"/>'
}


function SaveFields($post_id)
{
$screen = get_current_screen();
if(strcmp($screen->post_type, 'customlist') !=0)
   return;

$Desc = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'bizdesc ' ] ); 
$Name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'YourName' ] ); 
}
```

The standard input field comes in nicely and correctly.  The textarea field does not.  Not sure why?

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `textarea` doesn't have a `name`.

Comment: Is there code missing from `SaveFields`? All it does is assign variables, but I don't see any code that saves those variables to a database/file/etc

Comment: Tom, no code is missing.  The code that pulls the values is the _POST.

Comment: Found the problem.  Partially to Sally, who made me look at the input names more closely.  Name mismatch in a another part of the code.  Thanks for your help Sally.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to add `name ="bizdesc"` to your `textarea`, so this

```
function DrawCallBack($post)
{
  $Record = GetDBRecord();
  echo '<textarea id="bizdesc" rows="2" cols="50">';
  echo $Record['BizDescp'];
  echo  '</textarea>';

  echo '<input type=text id="YourName" name="YourName"  value="' .$Record['Name'] .'"/>'
}
```

should be

```
 function DrawCallBack( $post )
 {
  $Record = GetDBRecord();
  echo '<textarea name="bizdesc" id="bizdesc" rows="2" cols="50">';
  echo esc_textarea( $Record['BizDescp'] );
  echo  '</textarea>';

  echo '<input type="text" id="YourName" name="YourName"  value="' .esc_attr( $Record['Name'] ) .'"/>';
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget to use `esc_textarea` else someone can put `</textarea>` in the textarea to insert arbitrary HTML. Same with the value and `esc_attr`, the missing escaping allows various security breaches

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  It was a field naming problem.

Comment: In that case, up-vote the answer which helped you solve the problem and select it as accepted answer, This will help other to find correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: truly that was the answer.  I wrote the question, the name of the field was wrong.